# T-SQL cannot create SQL Server database file on mounted docker volume

Tags: sql-server, docker, t-sql

I'm trying to create a database in docker and have the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files be created on a mounted volume so they're not lost when the container shuts down. I followed [Microsoft's instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=cs1-bash) and added the volume to their example command like so:

```sh
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=<MY_PASSWORD>' \
  -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 \
  -v ~/mssql/data:/var/data \
  -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

Here's the SQL used to create the database and the files:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [MY_DB]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'MY_DB', FILENAME = N'/var/data/MY_DB.mdf' , SIZE = 204800KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'MY_DB_log', FILENAME = N'/var/data/MY_DB_log.ldf' , SIZE = 860160KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
```

I know this currently works if you're on a Windows machine running everything without docker because that's how we currently do it. However, when I try to execute the above SQL from inside the container (by connecting with a RDBMS), I get the error:

> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) while attempting to open or create the physical file '/var/data/SVT_MVP.mdf'

I tried `exec`ing into the container and running the SQL as root, but I get the same error. For funsies I even tried to chmod the mapped host directory to 0777 but no dice.

Another note is that everything works perfectly fine if there is no volume mounted. At this point I'm questioning if the volume part is worth it or even needed. I'm pretty new to docker.

Comment: The default location for datafile for SQL Server on Linux is `/opt/var/mssql/data`, did you bind the wrong path?

Comment: @Larnu Tried changing the volume bit to `-v ~/mssql/data:/opt/var/mssql/data` to no avail. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those curious, [mounting volumes on macos has had issues since 2017](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/12). Instead you have to create a data volume (named volume):

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=<MY_PASSWORD>' \
  -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 \
  -v sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql/data \
  -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

Thank you to Larnu who pointed me in the right direction.